# Nexus repository unable to resolve snapshot artifact

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have this old project that i need to run via Jenkins against our nexus repo server. There is however one dependency that i cannot get to sync.

I did however have managed to get the dependency on my local (i dont even know how i managed to do it)

[image]

when i rename those folders and run the below command i get the error

```
> mvn dependency:resolve -U

Could not find artifact com.autentia.web.rest:spring-wadl-generator:pom:1.1-SNAPSHOT in aais-build (http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-public/)
```

this is the dependency, it was added in 2014 according to the git logs

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.autentia.web.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-wadl-generator</artifactId>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

this is my local env

```
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.1\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
Java version: 11.0.18, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Any help is apricated as im not an ops or a java dev :(

Edit .. i have tried to manually add it

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.autentia.web.rest
    -DartifactId=spring-wadl-generator
    -Dversion=1.1-SNAPSHOT
    -Dpackaging=jar
    -Dfile=spring-wadl-generator-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    -DgeneratePom=true
    -DrepositoryId=myrepo
    -Durl=http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-releases/
```

settings.xml

```
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>myrepo</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>350a5609-0147-4c00-b177-0957966cc4c3</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

but that resulted in the following error (credentials are good)

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: C:\Users\Ric\.m2\repository\com\autentia\web\rest\spring-wadl-generator\1.1-SNAPSHOT\spring-wadl-generator-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: C:\Users\Ric\.m2\repository\com\autentia\web\rest\spring-wadl-generator\1.1-SNAPSHOT\spring-wadl-generator-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository: C:\Users\Ric\.m2\repository\com\autentia\web\rest\spring-wadl-generator\1.1-SNAPSHOT\spring-wadl-generator-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployFileMojo.execute (DeployFileMojo.java:283)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: A snapshot is most cases is deleted after a few weeks (often after a few days) in repository managers at latest after creating a release...

Comment: it looks like its just been abandoned https://github.com/autentia/wadl-tools/blob/master/spring-wadl-generator/pom.xml

Answer (score -1):

So what i ended up doing was uploading the dependency to nexus with out the "SNAPSHOT" and just changed the the config accordingly

[image]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.autentia.web.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-wadl-generator</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```